# x86 Compare command destination syntax

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm "debugging" a piece of x86 code - the preface being fine a series of 5 numbers from the code that "unlock" it, it's jumping around a lot in memory + math with the numbers that hold it.

I've traced what I need to input before the first "jump", it's:

```
cmp    %eax,0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)
```

I understand that this command is `cmp s, d` where I am taking d-s and setting EFLAGS. But what is `D 0x80498d4(, %ebx,4)` in this instance? Clearly something is being done to register `%ebx`, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's AT&T [memory reference syntax](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html).

AT&T's `displacement(base register, offset register, scalar multiplier)` syntax converts to Intel's `[base register + displacement + offset register * scalar multiplier]` syntax (which I think is much easier to understand).

So `cmp %eax,0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)` in AT&T syntax is equivalent to `cmp [80498d4h + ebx*4], eax` in Intel syntax.

The instruction reads in English as "compare the contents of register EAX with the contents of memory at address 0x80498d4+(EBX*4)".